# Firebase-functions auth failure after Firebase-tools upgrade

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

ERROR : @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Provided authentication credentials for the app named "[DEFAULT]" are invalid. This usually indicates your app was not initialized correctly. Make sure the "credential" property provided to initializeApp() is authorized to access the specified "databaseURL" and is from the correct project.

This error just started showing up with my app after I updated firebase-tools to 6.3.1. Was working great for months prior. To make matter worse.... there seems to be an endless loop in the call which, I am unable to find.

According to the Firebase docs and vids I have initialized the script correctly.

1. Deleted and redeployed the function
2. Changed rules to allow all read/write capabilities
3. Updated IAM permissions within Google dev console (although this seems foreign to me as I'm an IOS dev by nature)

```
 const admin = require('firebase-admin');
 const stripe = require("stripe")("sk_***********");

 stripe.setApiVersion('2018-09-24');

 admin.initializeApp();

 exports.chargeCustomer = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

 const _amount = req.query.amount;
 const _id = req.query.customerId;
 const _uid = req.query.uid;

 console.log('Charge customer started');

 stripe.charges.create({
     amount: _amount,
     customer: _id,
     currency: "usd"
 }, (err, charge) => {
     if (err !== null) {
         console.log("Error charging customer: ", err);
         res.status(500).send(err);
         return;
     } else {
         console.log('Stripe returned. Starting Firebase');

-below is where things go haywire-

         admin.database().ref(`/users/${_uid}/balance`)
             .once("value", (snap) => { 

                 admin.database().ref(`/users/${_uid}    /`).update({"some:data"}, (err) => {
                     if (err !== null) {

                         res.status(301).send(err.message);
                         return;
                     } else {
                         res.status(200).send(true);
                         return;
                     }
                 })
               }
             }).catch((err) => {
                 console.log("error getting balance: " + err);
                 res.status(301).send(err);
                 return;
             })
     }
 });
})
```

Comment: Did you update all of the related libraries?
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/99#issuecomment-421774710
npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
npm install --save firebase-functions@latest
npm install --save firebase-admin@latest

Comment: I've applied the npm tools mentioned.  Also added a firebase web app(which its not) to input a config to my initialization.  Still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

1. In your project go to Project Settings > Service Accounts > FirebaseAdminSdk. Copy the code for initialization.
2. Generate a new key to download and place in your project folder.
3. Update var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json")
4. Deploy